# База данных городов

Tags: android

Нашел базу городов Украины. Кому нужно, вот [она](http://www.wiseguys.com.ua/ukraine_cities.sql).  Мне нужно чтоб когда пользователь вводил первую букву отображалась подсказка в виде слова из этой базы данных. как это организовать. кто-то может уже делал подобное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoCompleteTextView используйте.